# Will "hiding" contacts on Google Contacts affect other apps' behavior?

Tags: contacts, google-contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-8, hidden, phone-app

I manage my contacts on my Google account. There is a feature in Google Contacts where one can "hide" selected contacts, as follows. If you go to [contacts.google.com](https://contacts.google.com/), click the three dots to the right of a contact, then click "Hide from contacts" in the menu, the contact will be moved to Other Contacts.

[image: Top half of menu for a contact]

I prefer to keep my digital data organized, and shortening my contacts list will help. However, I'm not sure what the effect of hiding a contact is (other than it not displaying in the contacts list on a contacts app).

We're talking about a contact that I'm not likely to communicate with in the future, but it would still be better for me to save their details, for example in the unlikely event that they phone me. **If a hidden contact phones me (on my Samsung Galaxy S8), will my stock phone app show me who is calling?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the caller will **not** be identified if the contact is hidden in Google Contacts.

The contact will be removed from the contacts list in the stock Samsung contacts app.

I tested this by calling my mobile with my work phone. I hid my work phone number in [contacts.gooogle.com](https://contacts.google.com/), and I also had to remove the number from my personal information in my Samsung Account, as well as my Samsung Account in my secure folder.

Answer (score -1):

"hiding" means hiding the contacts from the contacts app only , it will tells who's calling. I'm saying that it is only used by the app

Comment: Why do you mention "it doesn't mean hiding the details"?

Comment: My primary question is whether the phone app will tell me who is calling if the contact is hidden in Google Contacts.

Comment: it will tells who's calling. I'm saying that it is only used by the app.

Comment: Your answer needs to convince others who have the same question.